# Why use が in the sentence below?

Tags: particle-が

Why use が in the sentence below? Would を be equally correct?

> このピアノはとてもいい音**が**します。

Comment: Rather than try to explain the reason for the "〜がする" pattern, I would just memorize it for certain words: 音、匂い、色、even things like 吐き気 and 頭痛. Also know that you generally cannot replace が with を in these cases.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39316/discussion-on-question-by-orandajin-why-use--in-the-sentence-below).

Comment: Thnak you very much. This answer was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The structure of Japanese in SOV, on the other hand English's is SVO.

If here you take the particle を，piano would become the object, and

> はとてもいい音がします。

mening, in English "has very good tunes".

So if you put the を instead Object comes first, that would sound strange, instead the particle は needs to come to make the Subject.

Thanks.